# SonarQube PageDefenition interface not found in the plugin API 6.2.1

Tags: sonarqube

The official documentation tells to create pages while creating a plugin using the PageDefenition interface(org.sonar.api.web.page.PageDefinition). But the interface is not found in the Maven  dependency I am using which is the latest one available
 class not found. I am using the following dependency which is the latest one available as of now.

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarqube</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

The very first sentence [on that page](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Creating+a+Page) says that the functionality described there is available "since SonarQube 6.3". You are on 6.2, which is why the interface isn't found in your Maven dependency.

Comment: So the documentation there is for  6.3 which not released yet. So where can find the documentation for 6.2

Comment: @SufailKhan, you can't add a page in 6.2.

Comment: @ G. Ann - So the ruby based widgets are the only possible way to add a web extension?   On the same page, it says that "the prior mechanism relying on Ruby has been dropped in 6.1". So for 6.2, neither I can use Ruby to create a widget nor I can create a page?

Comment: In 6.2 you can do neither

Comment: @ G. Ann,   Does that mean I can't create a plugin for the Web layer if I am using 6.2 ?   I was able to  create metrics,measures and sensor extensions but to display my calculated custom results, please let me know the standard way in  SonarQube 6.2.

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam My organization uses 6.2 right now and I'm asked to create a plugin. Does this mean that I have to wait till the release of 6.3 ? Can I expect the 6.3 release anytime soon?

Comment: Your measures will automatically be displayed in the Measures domain.